# Coded auto-layout not working properly for UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I am working on a feeds page using a UITableView, and I am trying to set a dynamic height fro the cells (to adapt according to the content.)

I have created a custom class for the cells, here's the code:

```
class cellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UINavigationControllerDelegate {



//OUTLETS
@IBOutlet weak var usernameLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var profileImg: UIImageView!



override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code



    usernameLbl.text = "Username"
    usernameLbl.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()

    profileImg.layer.cornerRadius = profileImg.frame.size.width/2
    profileImg.layer.masksToBounds = true


    profileImg.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: profileImg, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100.0))

    contentView.addSubview(profileImg)

    contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: profileImg, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100.0))




}
```

And then, in the ViewDidLoad() method of the View Controller that controls the table view, I added the following:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160.0
```

However, the cells are not adapting at all since the height is still smaller than the content.

Comment: did imageView frame affect the changes according to the content?

Comment: Sorry, what does it mean?

Comment: u need each cell with different height according to the content,  right?

Answer (score 0):

I think your Constraint is complete correct but the problem is that you can't build a UITableView with dynamic TableViewCells with different heights for every cell. I tried that myself but in a dynamic UITableViewCell the attribute rowHeight of the tableView (tableView.rowHeight). So this rowHeight will override each different height of your cells which are defined by your Constraints.

Comment: I've read that it is possible to do it, but I never found a complete expalanation of how.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for the problem:

You can use the function 'heightForRowAtIndexPath' of the UITableViewDelegate like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(100)
}
```